# Symbols instead of p-value numbers on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, p-value, ggpubr

I created the following data and plot. How can I replace the p-value with symbols?

- If p-value is more than 0.05 - Don't show it,
- If p-value is between 0.01 to 0.05, display *
- If p-value is less than 0.01, display **

Is there a package for it? Can anyone offer an example?

I found that I can add "label = "p.signif" to stat_compare_means, but it display "ns" instead of not displaying it.

```
df <- data.frame("Class" = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
                             "B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B",
                             "C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C"), 
                   "Subject" = c("Math","Math","Math","Reading","Reading","Reading","Writing","Writing","Writing",
                                 "Math","Math","Math","Reading","Reading","Reading","Writing","Writing","Writing",
                                 "Math","Math","Math","Reading","Reading","Reading","Writing","Writing","Writing"),
                   "Score" = c(round(runif(27,0,100))))

library("ggplot2")

comp <- list (c("A","B"), c("A", "C"),  c("B", "C"))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Class, y = Score, color = Subject)) + 
  facet_wrap(~Subject) +
  geom_violin(trim = FALSE) +
  stat_compare_means(aes(group = Subject), method = "t.test", comparisons = comp)
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you are using `functions` of `ggpubr` package. Adding `label = "p.signif", hide.ns = TRUE` will do:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Class, y = Score, color = Subject)) + 
  facet_wrap(~Subject) +
  geom_violin(trim = FALSE) +
  stat_compare_means(aes(group = Subject), method = "t.test", 
                     label = "p.signif", hide.ns = TRUE, 
                     comparisons = comp)
```

[image]

Comment: hide.ns = TRUE does hide the ns, but it still shows the brackets. Is it possible to hide the brackets as well?

Comment: You can hide all but I cann't find a way to hide the `ns` ones through `args`. I guess it may still possible by changing the original code of `stat_compare_means`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `symnum.args` in `stat_compare_means` and assign `cutpoints` and `symbols` based on our requirement.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Class, y = Score, color = Subject)) + 
   facet_wrap(~Subject) +
   geom_violin(trim = FALSE) +
  stat_compare_means(aes(group = Subject), method = "t.test", comparisons = comp, 
                 symnum.args = list(cutpoints = c(0, 0.01, 0.05, Inf), 
                                    symbols = c("**", "*", "")))
```

[image]

Comment: Like the previous option, it still shows the brackets. Is it possible to hide the brackets as well?

Comment: @MDev you can use `bracket.size = 0` but it will remove brackets from all of them and keep only the stars.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the brackets only for ns?